# How to extract bold letters words between strong tags from each rows of a column?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have string that have bold letters words between strong tags. there are 50983 rows in a column nameds as notes_0. one of such rows is :

```
'The Candidate Status has now been updated from <strong>CV Submitted</strong> and <strong>Feedback Pending</strong> to <strong>Interview 1</strong> and <strong>Scheduled</strong> with Stage Date 05 July, 2018, 3:30 am IST - UTC +05:30.<br/><br/>Rahul has added the following note : "L1 Scheduled on 07/05/18 at 330 AM IST(6 PM EST)".'
```

I want that in other column and same row number the row should contain word "Interview 1" (ie, the word that is after 'to')

Comment: [`(?<=<strong>).*?(?=<\/strong>)`](https://regex101.com/r/CM63Xq/1/) would do it but it's not fool-proof.

Comment: please write full codes as i am a new learner

Comment: @AamerAshfaque that's not what SO is for. At least show that you have tried *something*. Even if you want to learn, by trying things yourself first will be *much* more valuable to yourself than just copy/pasting code. Especially the code you are asking for is on the first page on the BeautifulSoup docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions not very clear but I will give it a shot with the information you provided. The following script will give you the word you are looking for:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = 'The Candidate Status has now been updated from <strong>CV Submitted</strong> and <strong>Feedback Pending</strong> to <strong>Interview 1</strong> and <strong>Scheduled</strong> with Stage Date 05 July, 2018, 3:30 am IST - UTC +05:30.<br/><br/>Rahul has added the following note : "L1 Scheduled on 07/05/18 at 330 AM IST(6 PM EST)".'

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
bold_words = soup.find_all('strong')
print(bold_words[2].text)
```

Some remarks:

- You did not state if the number of "bold" tags is stable. So blindly accessing index `2` is iffy
- This example is almost directly gleamed from the first page of the BeautifulSoup docs. And you did not show any code that you already tried. Which leads me to believe that you did not read the docs and immediately came to SO for a quick answer. In the future, at least show your existing code with the error you are getting.

Comment: i did not tried anything because i am doing this first time.

Comment: In which case, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what if i have such str in rows? how to append it to a new column with  same index?

Comment: I'll be glad to help, but this seems like a new question. If you formulate this as a new question, with example data and code that you tried so far (see the link I posted above) I'll have a look. You have to understand that in programming there are many ways to solve a problem and without example data and code, it is almost impossible to give a good answer.